# Setting a Different, custom notification sound in Gmail Calendar for individual events

Tags: notifications, gmail, calendar, google-calendar

I am a teacher with a schedule that has me all over the school constantly. Is there a way to set or create a **different** notification sound for ***each different, individual event*** in my day on my Gmail calendar? I have a Galazy S20 FE 5G if that matters. Thank you for any help at all!